# Returning a value from a Promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, q

I would like to call the Google Maps Geocoding API using a Promise like this:

```
function makeGeoCodingRequest(address,bounds)
{
    /*
        Input parameters:
            address:a string
            bounds: an object of class google.maps.LatLngBounds(southWest,northEast)

        This will return a set of locations from the google geocoding library for the given query
     */
    var url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + address + "&key=AIzaSyD9GBloPC20X-1kWRo7sm_0z5xvCiaSd3c";
    var promise,response;
    var messages={
            "ZERO_RESULTS":"No results were found",
            "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT":"We are over the query limit.Wait awhile before making a request",
            "REQUEST_DENIED":"Request was denied,probably using a bad or expired API Key",
            "INVALID_REQUEST":"Request was sent without the required address,component or component",
            "UNKNOWN_ERROR": "There was an error somewhere on Google's servers" 
    };
    if(address)
        promise=Q($.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + address + "&key=API_KEY"
        }));
        return promise.then(function(data) {
            if (data.status === "OK") return data;
            else    console.error(messages[data.status]);
            return null;    
        });
}
```

When I call the function `makeGeoCodingRequest` request,I find that I obtain a promise instead of a value:

```
 var geo=makeGeoCodingRequest(address);
 console.log(Q.isPromise(geo));//returns true
```

Why isnt promise.then executed before the value was returned? How can I obtain a value from this promise instead of another promise?

Comment: promise don't give out value, instead you pass in the function that is going to use the value into the promise using `.then()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you depend on a promise in order to return your data, you must return a promise from your function.

Once 1 function in your callstack is async, all functions that want to call it have to be async as well if you want to continue linear execution. 
( async = return a promise )

Notice that your `if` statement does not have braces and thus only the first statement after it will not be executed if the condition fails.

I fixed it in this example. Notice the remarks I added.

```
if(address){
    promise=Q($.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + address + "&key=API_KEY"
    }));
    return promise.then(function(data) {
        // whatever you return here will also become the resolve value of the promise returned by makeGeoCodingRequest
        // If you don't want to validate the data, you can in fact just return the promise variable directly
        // you probably want to return a rejected promise here if status is not what you expected
        if (data.status === "OK") return data;
            else console.error(messages[data.status]);
        return null;    
    });
}
```

You must call `makeGeoCodingRequest` in the following fashion.

```
makeGeoCodingRequest(address,bounds).then(function(data){
    // this will contain whatever 
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: If I instead deciede to use `promise.then(...)` and `return promise` and then use `makeGeoCodingRequest(address,bounds).then(...)`,would it still be the same?

Comment: Yes, The promise returned by `makeGeoCodingRequest` will have the same value of the return value inside your `promise.then` handler. You can reject by returning something like `Q.reject(new Error("Http request failed" +  data.status))`

Comment: Thank you for the answer,everything works,including Q.reject.

Answer (score 3):

> I find that I obtain a promise instead of a value

Yes, because the operation is asynchronous and returns a promise which represents the future value.

> Why isnt promise.then executed before the value was returned?

Because it's asynchronous. `.then` will ([must](http://promisesaplus.com/)) never execute its callback before it returns another promise.

> How can I obtain a value from this promise instead of another promise?

You are getting the value in the callback:

```
makeGeoCodingRequest(address).then(function(geo) {
    console.log(geo)
    console.log(Q.isPromise(geo)); // false
    // do anything with the value here
})
// if you need to do anything with the result of the callback computation:
// you're getting back another promise for that!
```

It's impossible to obtain it synchronously from the promise ([many have tried](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/1048572)). That would mean blocking execution, which we don't want - let's stay async and non-blocking!

Comment: Very well explained. It might be interesting to give references to 'how to return the response from an AJAX call' and other questions relating to the issue.

Comment: What you are essentially saying is that any thing you want to do must be done inside the `then` method using the `data` I obtain as an `argument` in the `callback` to it.Just like `callbacks`,I guess.

Comment: Yes, [just like callbacks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572). Only that you get another promise back for the result of the callback, which makes them chainable.

Comment: And you get the possibility of unified error handling thrown in for free.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a promise from the function makeGeoCodingRequest. That is a good thing according to me, this helps you chain any more async calls if required in future. What I would suggest is to use a .then() on the returned promise and check if the promise has any returned value or error in the following manner.

```
var geoPromise = makeGeoCodingRequest(address); 
geoPromise.then(
   onSuccess(result){
       // You can use the result that was passed from the function here.. 
   }, 
   onFailure(response){
      // Handle the error returned by the function.
   }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want your code to wait until the asynchronous action is completed before continuing (BAD IDEA - the page will freeze while the request is completing) then add `async: false` to the ajax request's parameters.

My recommendation, though, is to have `makeGeoCodingRequest` return nothing directly - and simply give it an extra argument, `requestCallback` so that its caller can pass in a function that will be called when the data is available. Call that function, with the resulting data, inside of your `promise.then` function.

Comment: If there's a problem with my answer, perhaps someone could give a suggestion to improve it?

Comment: Your recommendation of making sync requests does not address the fact that OP is not understanding the promises concept. Besides that, it's wrong. You need to set a `async:false` in order to achieve a sync request. Like you noticed your self, in almost any circumstance, that's a bad idea. Introducing a callback in the function is also a bad idea, as clearly `makeGeoCodingRequest` should just return a promise, mixing both is an anti pattern and confusing for a beginner.

Comment: Ah, correct; I got the async value wrong. That part was actually to give an explanation of why his code can't simply return a value so easily. I guess I wasn't personally familiar with ideologies of which functions should continue to use the given 'promise' object, and which should transfer to a simplistic function; so that's actually new for me. I did not suggest he should use both.

Comment: Your answer is still suggesting he should use both.

Comment: No it isn't. Please read it more closely. The first paragraph begins with "If you want your code to wait..." and also denotes that's a bad idea. The second paragraph is an alternative.

Comment: The first paragraph suggest something the OP definitely shouldn't be doing, it should not even be mentioned in your answer. The second paragraph suggests mixing promises with callbacks. ( your adding a callback to a function that returns a promise) That is an anti pattern. You need to reformat your answer entirely, or delete it, sorry...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60096/discussion-between-katana314-and-willem-dhaeseleer).